# How is Nautilus file manager GUI programmed?

Tags: nautilus, gui

Since nautilus is written in C, how is the GUI created?

Is there a specific C framework that allows for GUI creation or is it done some other way?

Comment: Nautilus uses gtk toolkit. http://www.gtk.org

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know which version of GTK by any chance?

Comment: GTK 3.18 is used on 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is written in C mostly, as evident from the project's [github](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus) page:

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) it uses GTK3 as of version 2.32.

If you want to create GUI with C, there's not much choice - GTK is the best option ( although I'll hint at something known as [Borland's Turbo C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450081/3701431) which is like straight from the 1980s). I'd suggest you move up to C++. With C++ there's GTK and Qt options.